# I can't create a universal 10 project after upgrading from windows 8.1 pro to windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

**Problem**

I have upgraded my `windows 8.1 pro 64 bits` to `windows 10 64 bits` to work on universal apps with `windows 10`,but what I note is there many errors when I create a new universal 10 project with `visual Studio 2015`.

**Tried**

- modified the installation of `visual Studio`
- and the universal tools are already installed
- then I have repaired `visual Studio`

but always I have a problem in opening a universal 10 Project (those errors are not appeared when I come to create a universal `windows 8.1` app project).

**Question**

those errors appears only in `App.xaml.cs`,any help please how can I solve the error

[image]

thanks for help

Comment: What are the errors you're getting?

Comment: I have updated my post Sir

Comment: Please *type* the errors rather than posting a screenshot. Images cannot be searched in, and are a waste of bandwidth when text is better. In some versions of Visual Studio, you can right-click and copy them as text.

Comment: thanks Sir Wai Ha Leefor your reply,it works with the solution of Romasz :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I stumbled on the same problem. I was able to fix it like this:

- open Nuget package manager, show installed packages, uninstall the one with name *Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform*
- now search net for package with the same and install it.

After this I was able to build successfully the project.

Also please check if you have installed the latest VS update - [link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx)