# 'Windows.Storage.StorageFile File = await FilePicker.PickSingleFileAsync()' not working

Tags: c#, xaml, compiler-errors, win-universal-app

I have the following code that shows a File Picker in an application:

```
var FilePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
FilePicker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
FilePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder;
FilePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".pcs");
FilePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".pcp");

Windows.Storage.StorageFile File = await FilePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

However, `Windows.Storage.StorageFile File = await FilePicker.PickSingleFileAsync()` causes this error during compilation:

> Error CS4036 'IAsyncOperation<StorageFile>' does not contain a
>   definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'IAsyncOperation<StorageFile>'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive for 'System'?)

Why is this happening? I got the code from MSDN. Could someone please help me?

Note: I am programming for Universal Windows.

Comment: Do you have the using directive for System as it indicates?

Comment: If you get lots of errors also in `using` directives, then try to follow [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34197683/2681948) - from unknown reasons for some projects you need to readd nuget package.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are missing the obvious reference to `System` in your usings.

```
using System;
```

Why do you need this reference and why it complains it is missing a seemingly unused method?

With `await`, it actually calls `WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions.GetAwaiter`, an extension method over `IAsyncOperation` (to get the `TaskAwaiter` to await). Since `WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions` resides in the `System` namespace, you need that `using` to get the extension method.

Comment: Hope the `IntelliSense` could be much more intelligent detecting a very simple mistake as this

Comment: I have already "using System;". How to fix it? :

Comment: I am having the same problem, I am using "using System;", still facing the same error.